# How to delete the Swap partition?

Tags: partitioning

I have Ubuntu 14.10 thats dual booted (with windows 7) with 6 GB of RAM and i want to delete the swap partition without having any errors when booting into Ubuntu if its possible how?

**BTW my Linux swap is taking about 5 GB and thats a lot.**

[image]

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/372143/what-is-the-safest-way-to-remove-a-swap-partition

Comment: See [this Q&A to learn why you should not just remove /swap](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49109/i-have-16gb-ram-do-i-need-32gb-swap). But we can have it smaller if we are in fear of running short of hard disk space.